# Determining currently playing spotify playlist?

Tags: spotify

I'm current building a spotify playlist app.  There are currently multiple playlists that surface on one page, but when a user loads a playlist, I'd like to update the one subscribe button on the page with the playlist that's currently playing.

I'm able to use the player model to determine the currently playing track.  What's the best way to do the same for the playlist?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, at the moment user playlists aren't accessible through the Spotify Apps API unless the user directly provides them to you by dropping them on your application. This includes seeing which playlist is currently playing, if any.

Comment: Thanks sir.  I actually have all the playlist information.  After digging through, looks like by hitting player.context I get the uri for the playlist that I set.